# iOS 10 HLS 404 playlist error handling

Tags: ios, http-status-code-404, http-live-streaming

In iOS 10, if the m3u8 master playlist request returns 404, the status property on a AVPlayerItem doesn't translate into Failed state (AVPlayerItemStatusFailed). This makes error handlers inoperative as dictated in AVPlayerItem documentation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem

Has anyone found any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the URL returns a 404 code state, than before playing or adding the item, you can make a **URLSession**  with a request containing the URL, and then you can check the response that is returned. If it has status code 200, it means it's good to go, if it has a value of 404, then it's faulty.


**Example in Swift 3**

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://yourstringhere.com")!)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        //handle if error != nil and if response.statusCode is 200 or 404
    }

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4 Solution

You can track the AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry notification. For a 404 error, the following code would print "HTTP 404: File Not Found"

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry, object: avPlayer?.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        print(avPlayer.currentItem?.errorLog()?.events.last?.errorComment)
}
```

Also, the second half of this video has useful info about best practices for client-side error handling. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html